# THREE JS Morph Different Geometries

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, tweenjs

I'm using the `EdgesGeometry` to render my objects. Right now I'm looking for a way to morph Tetrahedron into Octahedron, Octahedron into Box, Box into Sphere and in the reverse sequence. Went through a lot of documentations and discussions and videos - everything is either outdated, deprecated or just miser text explanations. I found a way to morph `BufferGeometry` objects using `TWEEN.js`, but in my case I need to morph `EdgesGeometry` objects.
I'd be very grateful if someone gave me some good links or even code examples of how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Morph targets](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html) has great results. Otherwise, loop the vertices and lerp to a corresponding Vertex3. You could use a Post-Processing Effects shader to soften the transition, such as Bokeh or metaballs.